Getting problem while working with API Request in React Native
While working with Api in React Native,. The API data will not display, as I checked so many times, but nothing works, and the same API works on my ReactJS project, so it will display the data. Can anyone explain how I can fix the problem of data not displaying in React Native and it showing an error on my console?
Error fetching data: [AxiosError: Network Error]
Here is my code :-
import { DataTable, Text } from 'react-native-paper';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { View } from 'react-native'; 

const Gender = () => {
  const [datas, setDatas] = useState([]);

  function getData() {
    axios.get('https://localhost:7199/api/Newone2')
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        setDatas(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      });
  }
  

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Text>Api data:-</Text>

      {datas.length ? datas.map((item) => (
        <View key={item.id}> {/* Ensure each element has a unique key */}
          <Text>id: {item.id}</Text>
          <Text>id: {item.name}</Text>
        </View>
      )) : null}
    </>
  );
};

export default Gender;

And the code that i used in React Js Project:-
const Loginpage = () => {
    const [datas, setDatas] = useState([])
    

    const { control, formState, reset, handleSubmit } = useForm();


    function getData() {
        axios.get('https://localhost:7199/api/Newone2').then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data)
            setDatas(response.data);
        });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getData();
    }, [])



    const handleDelete = (id) => {
        axios.delete(`https://localhost:7199/api/Newone2/${id}`)
            .then(() => {
                getData();
            })
    }

    





    return (
        <div>
            <h1 className='text-center'>Display Data</h1>
            <div className='text-center'>
                <a href='/' className='btn btn-primary table-bordered table-striped mt-2 table-hover  justify-content-center' >Create Data</a></div>

            <div className='col-md-12 mt-3'>
                <table className='table table-bordered table-striped table-danger table-hover'>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Name</th>

                            <th>Phone</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>password</th>
                            <th>Edit</th>
                            <th>Delete</th>
                        </tr>

                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {datas.map((data) => {
                            return (
                                <>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{data.id}</td>
                                        <td>{data.name}</td>
                                        <td>{data.phone}</td>
                                        <td>{data.phone}</td>
                                        <td>{data.password}</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <Link to={`/edit/${data.id}`} className='btn btn-primary'>Edit</Link>



                                        </td>
                                        <td><button className='btn btn-secondary' onClick={() => { if (window.confirm('Are you Sure??')) { handleDelete(data.id) } }}>Delete</button></td>

                                    </tr>
                                </>
                            );
                        })}

                    </tbody>
                </table>

             {
                datas.map((item)=>(
                    <div> <h1 key={item} > {item.name} </h1> </div>
                ))
             }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

My Response Body looks like this.
[
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Akash",
    "email": "akash@gmail.com",
    "phone": 789456,
    "password": 123
  }
]

Note:- It was just practice code.

I just got the answer to why it was not working in React Native. It is because Android emulators have different ways to handle network requests. We have to used 10.0.2.2:Your_PORT_NUMBER/ instead of localhost we have to place 10.0.2.2.
When you use localhost in the context of an Android emulator, it refers to the emulator's own loopback interface, not the host machine where the emulator is running. This is why when your React Native app running in the emulator tries to connect to localhost, it's attempting to connect to the emulator itself, not your development machine where your API might be running.
On the other hand, 10.0.2.2 is a special alias that Android emulators recognize, which points to the host machine's loopback interface (i.e., localhost) from within the emulator. This allows the emulator to communicate with services running on your development machine.
To summarize:
Use 10.0.2.2 when you want to access services running on your development machine from within the Android emulator.
Use localhost when you want to access services running on the same device (i.e., the emulator or physical device itself).
Updated Code:-
import { DataTable, Text } from 'react-native-paper';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { View } from 'react-native'; 

const Gender = () => {
  const [datas, setDatas] = useState([]);

  function getData() {
    axios.get('http://10.0.2.2:8090/api/getdata')
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        setDatas(response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      });
  }
  

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Text>Api data:-</Text>

      {datas.map((item, index) => (
  <View key={index}> 
    <Text>id: {item.ID}</Text>
    <Text>Name: {item.name}</Text>
  </View>
))}

    </>
  );
};

export default Gender;

Note:- In previous code i have used (.Net Core Api but now i have used Node js Api ).
